# timeout pandas read_csv stringio timeout

Tags: django, python-2.7, pandas

Pandas read_csv causes a timeout on my production server with python 2.7, django 1.6.5, apache and nginx. This happens only when using a string buffer like StringIO.StringIO or io.BytesIO. When supplying a filename as argument to read_csv everything works fine.
Debugging does not help because on my development server this problem does not occur.
Any ideas?

Comment: Debugging always helps. What differs in the 2 environments? Same version of pandas? Same python version? There's a million variables to consider. Please tell us more.

Comment: same python (2.7), same pandas (0.14)

Comment: same python, same pandas running in virtualenv.

Comment: weird thing is that the problem does not occur when running from commandline or in djangos development server, only when running under apache. This means it may be related to apache configuration. When I set the pareser engine to 'python' it works. Problem is that I need the c-engine in my code. Does the c-engine need special access or privileges?

Answer (score 0):

This is over a year old, but this is the only SO thread I found on this issue so thought I'd comment on what we did to fix it. It turns out there are issues with `pd.read_csv(FileObject, engine="C")` on an embedded wsgi process.  We ended up solving this issue by upgrading to pandas 0.17.0.  Another working solution was to run mod_wsgi in daemon mode as this issue seems to relate to some conflict in how MPM is running read_csv with the C-engine while in embedded mode. We still aren't quite sure what the exact issue is however...

Comment: I'm getting the same issue with pandas 0.19.0, so it's not solved yet!

Comment: @TangoAlee, is there any more information you can post about what you're seeing?

Comment: Got a great answer from the guru Graham Dumpleton. This `FIXED` the issue!! See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40028497/import-pandas-on-apache-server-causes-timeout-error/40031407?noredirect=1#comment67342198_40031407