# Import Pandas on apache server causes timeout error

Tags: python, django, apache, pandas, mod-wsgi

I've got a Django project working on an Apache server.

I installed pandas and want to use it to start manipulating data - however something odd is happening.

Anytime I use the `import pandas` on the production environment, the server will hang up and (after a while) throw a 408 timeout error.

I can comment out the `pandas` portion and the server responds normally without issue. I can't recreate it in the development environment or command line interface with django.

Here are the `httpd-app.conf` file:

```
Alias /tooltrack/static "C:/Users/myfolder/Bitnami Django Stack Projects/tooltrack/static/"
<Directory "C:/Users/myfolder/Bitnami Django Stack Projects/tooltrack/static/">
Options +MultiViews
AllowOverride All
<IfVersion < 2.3 >
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</IfVersion>
<IfVersion >= 2.3>
    Require all granted
</IfVersion>

<IfVersion < 2.3 >
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</IfVersion>
<IfVersion >= 2.3>
    Require all granted
</IfVersion> 
</Directory>


WSGIScriptAlias / 'C:/Users/myfolder/Bitnami Django Stack projects/tooltrack/tooltrack/wsgi.py'

<Directory "C:/Users/myfolder/Bitnami Django Stack projects/tooltrack/tooltrack">
Options +MultiViews
AllowOverride All
<IfVersion < 2.3 >
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</IfVersion>
<IfVersion >= 2.3>
    Require all granted
</IfVersion>

<IfVersion < 2.3 >
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</IfVersion>
<IfVersion >= 2.3>
    Require all granted
</IfVersion> 
</Directory>

<Directory "C:/Users/myfolder/Bitnami Django Stack projects/tooltrack">
Options +MultiViews
AllowOverride All
<IfVersion < 2.3 >
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</IfVersion>
<IfVersion >= 2.3>
    Require all granted
</IfVersion>
</Directory>
```

I know its hanging up on the import of pandas due to this:

```
def panda_dataframe_r():
print 'importing pandas ' + str(timezone.now())
import pandas
print 'import done ' + str(timezone.now())
```

I can see the `importing pandas` in the log, however no following `import done`

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try adding:

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

Various of the scientific packages that it is going to need will not work in Python sub interpreters. That directive will force the use of the main interpreter context.

Comment: Graham - thank you very much for the help. To be clear you are saying add it to the `httpd-app.conf`?

Comment: Thanks very much - completely solved the issue! This is the second time you've rescued me!

Comment: I use Flask and the proper file to edit is `/etc/apache2/sites-available/FlaskApp.conf`.  But this did the trick for me.