# Django Pandas AWS

Tags: python, django, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am attempting to deploy a Django project on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. One of my views makes use of Pandas to generate some data.

I was able to get Pandas to compile properly on my EBS hosted site. I was noticing however that the browser would become "hung" when I tried to access any pages. I removed the view with the Pandas and the pandas import and the problem went away. However, when I add the Pandas import back, the problem recurs, leading me to believe it is a problem with Pandas. Also, if I remove the view that utilizes Pandas, but keep the "import pandas" statement, the problem remains. As soon as I remove "import pandas as pd" the problem goes away.

When I SSH into the instance and run manage.py shell I can import Pandas properly and have no problems whatsoever - so I know Pandas has compiled properly.

I checked the logs and nothing jumps out at me. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You tagged this Django and mentioned Django in the title, but I don't see any django here... if you call a view that doesn't utilize Pandas, does that work? Have you tried a simpler Pandas invocation (whatever the equivalent of getting Pandas return 1+1 is)?

Comment: I updated my question to be more clear. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be with the apache wsgi.conf file. I do not understand all the details, but by looking at this answer I was able to resolve the problem.

[Import Pandas on apache server causes timeout error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40028497/import-pandas-on-apache-server-causes-timeout-error)

Answer (score 2):

I've had problems using panda w/django on a micro aws ec2 instance because of too little memory. Upgrading the instance solved the problem for me -

If you are using a t2.micro for example, i might be worth upgrading to a larger instance just to see if the problem magically disappears - like it did for me.

Perhaps not a completely satisfactory answer, but t might help you narrow down the problem.

Comment: Thank you. I had anticipated that and am using a t2.medium which I think should be ample memory. I will try a larger to see if it resolves the problem.

Comment: i changed to t2.large and still the same problem. any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry I don't. A low memory condition was my problem, and I thought it was worth a try since your symptoms sounded very similar.